# Image is mangled when displaying numpy array image in tkinter

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to display an image, procedurally generated by my code, into a canvas object. I don't want to use the canvas functions to generate these images because there's no good way (the screenshot and ghostcript methods are no good) to get pixel data out of the canvas.

I looked around for ways to generate the image pixels and settled on scikit-image, and then you can load the array as data in an image object in tkinter.

On the left is the pixel data displayed with matplotlib, on the right is the tkinter canvas with the same data displayed as a PhotoImage.

It's clear something is wrong.

[image]

This is my code:

```
from skimage.draw import polygon
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

def generate():
    
    # clear canvas
    canvas.delete("all")

    # make clean array
    img = np.ones((width, height, 3), dtype=np.double) * 0.75

    # randomly generate positions
    x_generated = np.random.uniform(0, width, 5)
    y_generated = np.random.uniform(0, height, 5)
    
    for x, y in zip(x_generated, y_generated):
        base_height = 70
        base_width = 70

        # generate the corners
        x0 = x - base_width/2
        x1 = x + base_width/2
        y0 = y - base_height/2
        y1 = y + base_height/2

        # create rectangle
        poly = np.array((
            (x0, y0),
            (x1, y0),
            (x1, y1),
            (x0, y1),
        ))

        rr, cc = polygon(poly[:, 0], poly[:, 1], img.shape)
        img[rr, cc, :] = 0.5

        # # canvas method. I don't want to use this!
        # canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill="red", outline="")
    
    # display generated image in tkinter canvas
    scaled_to_8bit = img * 255
    imgarray = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(scaled_to_8bit, 'RGB'))

    # create the canvas image object from the numpy array
    canvas.create_image(20, 20, anchor="nw", image=imgarray)
    
    # display pixel data for debugging
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    width = 1000
    height = 1000

    # Create a root window
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.configure(background="green")

    # Create a canvas widget
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=width, height=height)
    canvas.pack()

    # Create a button widget
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Generate", command=generate)
    button.pack()

    # start main tk loop
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `img` is an array of double values, therefore `scaled_to_8bit` is one as well. PIL can't process double values correctly. You have to convert them to unsigned bytes in numpy before giving the array to the PIL.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thank you this fixed it! Now I have another issue where if I remove the matplotlib functionality, the image is just blank.. I will create another question for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datatype of the blank image array was a double, but the image object doesn't support that format. I converted it to an 8 bit datatype just before displaying the image and this fixed the issue.

Note: there's still an issue where the image disappears when the matplotlib window is closed, but its a separate issue

```
from skimage.draw import polygon
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

def generate():
    
    # clear canvas
    canvas.delete("all")

    # make clean array
    img = np.ones((width, height, 3), dtype=np.float32) * 0.75

    # randomly generate positions
    x_generated = np.random.uniform(0, width, 5)
    y_generated = np.random.uniform(0, height, 5)
    
    for x, y in zip(x_generated, y_generated):
        base_height = 70
        base_width = 70

        # generate the corners
        x0 = x - base_width/2
        x1 = x + base_width/2
        y0 = y - base_height/2
        y1 = y + base_height/2

        # create rectangle
        poly = np.array((
            (x0, y0),
            (x1, y0),
            (x1, y1),
            (x0, y1),
        ))

        rr, cc = polygon(poly[:, 0], poly[:, 1], img.shape)
        img[rr, cc, :] = 0.5

        # # canvas method. I don't want to use this!
        # canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill="red", outline="")
    
    # display generated image in tkinter canvas
    scaled_to_8bit = img * 255
    newarr = scaled_to_8bit.astype(np.uint8)
    imgarray = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(newarr, 'RGB'))

    # create the canvas image object from the numpy array
    canvas.create_image(20, 20, anchor="nw", image=imgarray)
    
    # display pixel data for debugging
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    width = 1000
    height = 1000

    # Create a root window
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.configure(background="green")

    # Create a canvas widget
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=width, height=height)
    canvas.pack()

    # Create a button widget
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Generate", command=generate)
    button.pack()

    # start main tk loop
    root.mainloop()
```